# How to make a search engine for my comments

Tags: django, python-3.x, full-text-search, filtering

I am trying to make a search engine through the posted comments. The goal is to search the comments as easiest as possible. See below the architecture of the program:

**views.py**

```
class ComentarioListar (LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    login_url='/'
    redirect_field_name='redirigido'
    model = Comentario
    template_name = 'home/comentario_listar.html'

class busqueda (ListView):
    model=Comentario
    template_name='home/search.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs=Comentario.objects.filter()
        keywords=self.request.GET.get('q')
        if keywords:
            query=SearchQuery(keywords)
            vector=SearchVector('titulo')
            qs=qs.annotate(search=vector).filter(search=query)
            qs=qs.annotate(rank=SearchRank(vector,query)).order_by('-rank')
        return render(request, 'home/search.html', {'qs':qs} )
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^listar$', ComentarioListar.as_view(), name="listar"),
    url(r'^search$',busqueda, name="search"),]
```

**models.py**

```
class Comentario (models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    texto = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    autor = models.ForeignKey (Perfil, null=True, blank=True,         on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_publicacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tags, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.titulo)
```

**cometario_listar.html** (where I have created the search button)

```
<form id="searchform" action="search/" method="GET" accept-charset="utf-8">
      <button class="searchbutton" type="submit">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </button>
      <input class="searchfield" id="searchbox" name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search" id="busqueda">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**search.html**

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead class="thead-default">
      <tr>
        <td>Titulo</td>
        <td>Descripcion</td>
        <td>Autor</td>
        <td>Fecha de publicación</td>
        <td>Etiqueta</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% if qs %}
      {% for comentario in object_list %}

      <tr>
        <td>{{comentario.titulo}}</td>
        <td>{{comentario.texto}}</td>
        <td>{{comentario.autor}}</td>
        <td>{{comentario.fecha_publicacion}}</td>
        {% for tag in comentario.tag.all %}
            <td>{{ tag.nombre }}</td>   
        {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}  
      </tr>   

      {% else %}
      <h1>No hay registros de comentarios</h1>
      {% endif %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is that it does not work. 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/search/?q=nueva' appears correctly, but it does not make any filtering. Is it possible to use the same .html file (comentario_listar.html) to make the search?

thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi John, in your search.html template you are using variables you did not send them to the template

Comment: you don't have to use `Q` too

Comment: I have modified the view and the template search, but it does not still work

Comment: i have a website and i used a similar search read [this](https://github.com/mikeGHQ/SetTheCodeProject/blob/master/templates/base.html#L73) and [this](https://github.com/mikeGHQ/SetTheCodeProject/blob/master/blog/views.py#L41)

Comment: ok! thank you for your answer! it works with one to one objects but it does not with foreign key and many to many objects.